# "Enter at least undefined characters"

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

On the mobile web interface, when writing a comment and no characters entered, the interface displays that:

> Enter at least ***undefined*** characters

And, when I write 1 character, I see:

> 599 characters left

instead of the usual

> 14 more to go...

Screenshot of bug:

[image: Screenshot of issue]

The server-side logic isn't broken (I get an error when trying to submit those comments), but the client-side part looks erroneous.

The issue also applies to Meta.

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332701